# Ретрансляция платного Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi

имеется роутер tp link и платный Wi-Fi который не добивает до крайних комнат квартиры, есть ли способы ретранслировать этот Wi-Fi через роутер?

Comment: Да, если ваш роутер это позволяет. Смотрите описание вашей конкретной модели.

Comment: Опция будет называться WDS или Repeater